# Best Way To Migrating Huge numbers of Data Rows from Access To SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have several Access Database with more than 40000000 rows. I'm reading each row using a Data Reader and insert every row one by one into SQL Database. But it seems it will take weeks and even more!

Is there any way doing this migration faster?

Comment: Export to csv and load with BCP (any MS SQL version). LOAD DATA  (MySql) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: you may develop a small utility to import data from excel to sql. Copy all records which are in access file to excel file and perform import operations with the help of this utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend exporting your access database to a CSV files (or a number of CSV files), a guide is here: https://support.spatialkey.com/export-data-from-database-to-csv-file/

You can then using Bulk Import or SSIS to import the rows into SQL Server. A reference for this operation would be; http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

This way should be substantially faster.

An programmatic alternative would be using the SQLBulkCopy class; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I used Bulk Insert from CSV file, but it seems it does not support for Unicode characters like Arabic ones.

Comment: Which Bulk Insert method are you using? Probably this page will shed some light: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188289.aspx

Comment: still does not support Arabic chars :( I used the method in your second link in answer. I also add DATAFILETYPE ='widechar' to method but does not succee!.

Comment: When you say it does not succeed, what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error? If so, what error? Or do they just display incorrectly?

Comment: They just display incorrectly. But I have fix them by adding CODEPAGE = 'ACP', into insert method. Thank you Milney. Now everything is great and ultra FAST ;)